# Cannot initiate contentView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to create a button that takes over the whole page by using constraint layout. However, the screen shows nothing and I do not know what to do anymore. Any suggestions? I am trying to use the Fragment's equivalent for Activity.setContentView, but it seems that I cannot make it work.

```
class Login : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login) {
    lateinit var cl: ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var cs: ConstraintSet
    lateinit var btn: Button

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        cl = ConstraintLayout(requireContext())
        btn = Button(requireContext())
        btn.id = 5
        var lp1: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams =
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        cl.layoutParams = lp1
        var lp2: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams =
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0)
        btn.layoutParams = lp2
        btn.setText("bag pula")
        cl.addView(btn)
        cs = ConstraintSet()
        cs.clone(cl)
        cs.connect(btn.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        cs.connect(btn.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
        cs.connect(btn.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        cs.connect(btn.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        cs.applyTo(cl)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Login().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9zE3.png)
[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKoPi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a different yet simple approach

In your fragment.xml file create a button that takes over the entire fragment(using match parent for both height and width) and then inflate the fragment in your activity.
That should be the solution as your question suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You create the *ConstraintLayout* and add the button to it, but you never add the *ConstraintLayout* to the layout on the screen and created in `onCreateView()`. You would add it in the same way as you do the button. You have avoided a common error by generating new layout params for each view.

Since `onCreate()` runs before `onCreateView()`, you will either need to delay the creation of the *ConstraintLayout* until `onCreateView()` (my recommendation) or save it in `onCreate()` for later reference in `onCreateView()`. Once the layout in `onCreateView()` is inflated, you can add the *ConstraintLayout* to it.

That should get you going again. I suggest that you use the *Layout Inspector* available in Android Studio to take a look at the make up of you layout on an emulator or real device. The Layout Inspector can often offer clues on what is going (or not going) on.

A side note: When generating ids for view, do this:

`btn.id = View.generateViewId()`

instead of hard-coding a constant.